# Why does a locally scoped variable that hasn't been defined reference the instance variable of the same name?

Tags: ruby, scope, scope-resolution, narwhal

I came across an odd bug in my code that revealed an interesting behavior of ruby.  Hopefully someone can explain why it behaves this way.

I had a class with an instance variable @foo and a method that referenced a locally scoped variable foo.  I refactored part of the method out accidentally leaving the reference to foo; the variable no longer defined in the scope.  It ended up pointing to @foo instead.  Changing foo made changes to @foo and vice versa.

Simplified version:
EDIT : added ImOutOfNames.

```
class ImOutOfNames
    attr_accessor :foo # the culprit!
end

class Bar < ImOutOfNames
    def initialize
        @foo = "that is a tasty burger"
    end

    def bar_method_1
        foo = "Come on Yolanda, whats Fonzie like?"
        bar_method_2
    end

    def bar_method_2
        puts foo
    end
end
```

And the output of bar_method_1 and bar_method_2 was "that is a tasty burger".  I was expecting there to be an error, for example running the above code gets

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method
```

I even had a more senior developer come take a  look and he was somewhat baffled and confirmed the behavior.

Is this an expected behavior and I misunderstood how @variables work or is there something wrong?

Comment: Very odd.  There isn't an `attr_reader :foo` hiding in there somewhere, is there?  You're not misunderstanding anything.  If `def foo; @foo end` isn't defined (explicitly or via `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor`), `foo` should not be returning `@foo`

Comment: aha!  I just checked and there is indeed an attr_accessor :foo.

Comment: nice :)  gotta watch those magic methods.  Hook one of those answers up with a point :-P

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to give points yet :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your previous buggy code probably at an **attr_accessor**  definition that created a method **foo** that accessed to your instance variable,

You can have the same behavior if your code is like this:

```
class Bar

  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize
    @foo = "that is a tasty burger"
  end

  def bar_method_1
    foo = "Come on Yolanda, whats Fonzie like?"
    bar_method_2
  end

  def bar_method_2
    puts foo
  end
end
```

The attr_accessor call defines two methods in your object;

```
def foo
  @foo
end

def foo=(value)
  @foo = value
end
```

So in your case, when no local variable was defined, the method was used, but as you did not call attr_accessor in this example you posted the method was not defined and there was no local variable to use on **bar_method_2** so the call fails.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!

I went back and checked and there was an attr_accessor in its parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an attr accessor for your @foo instance variable? That's one way this could happen.

I'd recommend not using the same name for a locally scoped variable, in general, but you can find out if it's coming from some method with

```
self.method(:foo)
```

or if it's even defined with

```
defined? foo
```

Using the ruby runtime to your advantage definitely reduces the mysticism and magical nature of some code.